# Мерцание при mouseover / mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Делаю блок с социалками, при наведении на ту или иную иконку должен появляться блочёк с некой информацией. Проблема в том, что при `mouseover/mouseout` происходит какое-то мерцание добавляемого по наведению элемента. Причем такой эффект наблюдается у всех кнопок кроме fb, если курсор пересекает правую границу иконки.

Почему и как решить, подскажите пожалуйста. [Песочница](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/mWzjmW).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socialBtnsBlock = $('.social-buttons');
    var socialBtn = $('.social-buttons .btn');
    var toggleBlock = $('.social-buttons .toggle-item');
    var ta_begin = '<span class="toggle-item">';
    var ta_end = '</span>';

    socialBtn.on('mouseover', function() {
        var currentSocialBtn = $(this);
        var currentValue = currentSocialBtn.attr('data-value');
        $('.toggle-item').remove();
        currentSocialBtn.after(ta_begin+currentValue+ta_end);
        $('.toggle-item').css('display', 'inline-block');
    });

    socialBtn.on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.toggle-item').remove();
    });
})
```

```css
.social-buttons {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
.social-buttons .social-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;


}
.social-buttons .social-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.social-buttons .btn {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

.social-buttons .btn i {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.social-buttons .facebook-btn {
    color: #3b5998;
}
.social-buttons .twitter-btn {
    color: #00b6f1;
}
.social-buttons .google-plus-btn {
    color: #da5333;
}
.social-buttons .pinterest-btn {
    color: #bb232c;
}

.social-buttons .stumbleupon-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #f15a24;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
}

/* toggle item */
.social-buttons .toggle-item {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px; left: 0px;
    display: none;
    height: 27px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: default;
}
.social-buttons .toggle-item:after,
.social-buttons .toggle-item:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px; top: calc(50% - 4px);
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid #ccc;
}
.social-buttons .toggle-item:before {
    content: '';
    border-right: 4px solid #f9f9f9;
    left: -8px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>

<ul class="social-buttons">
    <li class="social-item">
        <span class="btn facebook-btn" data-value="facebook">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="social-item">
        <span class="btn twitter-btn" data-value="twitter">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="social-item">
        <span class="btn google-plus-btn" data-value="google plus">
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="social-item">
        <span class="btn pinterest-btn" data-value="pinterest">
            <i class="fa fa-pinterest-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <span class="toggle-item">
        some text
    </span>
</ul>
```

Comment: в каком браузре проверяли? попробуйте в разных

Comment: @AndRey, во всех браузерах кроме Хрома работает корректно.

UPD: корректно работает только в `codepen`, непосредственно на сверстанной странице то же поведение наблюдается во всех браузерах..

Comment: во-первых, не пойму зачем это делать при помощи js, во-вторых, раз уж *чуть-чуть* задумались о доступности, то делайте этот блок полностью доступным, в-третьих, проблема не воспроизводится (или интерпретируется мной не как "мерцание").

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, на странице полно карточек с таким блоком, не хотел плодить лишних элементов - это по первому вопросу. По второму замечанию - не совсем понятно о чём речь. Что касается третьего - эл-ты появляются/исчезают, как это еще назвать...

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас иконка выходит за границы кнопки, отсюда и срабатывание ивентов туда-сюда. Решается при помощи `overflow: hidden`.
2. Доступностью в вебе называется возможность пользоваться интерфейсом при помощи разных устройств, в т. ч. устройств ввода. В вашем случае интерфейс будет работать только при наличии мышки, с клавиатуры, например, нельзя открыть тултипы. Также есть люди с проблемами зрения, они пользуются читалками, так вот с читалки этот интерфейс недоступен совсем, даже нельзя будет прочитать внутренности — это просто набор тегов без какой-либо информации. У вас есть зачатки доступности в виде атрибута `aria-hidden="true"` — при помощи него этот тег будет скрыт для читалок (и это правильно, т. к. он пустой). Я бы рекомендовал вам добавить к каждому `<span class="btn">` атрибут `aria-label=""` с названием социальной сети. [Небольшая статья на хабре об этом](https://habrahabr.ru/post/323876/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var socialBtnsBlock = $('.social-buttons');
  var socialBtn = $('.social-buttons .btn');
  var toggleBlock = $('.social-buttons .toggle-item');
  var ta_begin = '<span class="toggle-item">';
  var ta_end = '</span>';

  socialBtn.on('mouseover', function() {
    var currentSocialBtn = $(this);
    var currentValue = currentSocialBtn.attr('data-value');
    $('.toggle-item').remove();
    currentSocialBtn.after(ta_begin + currentValue + ta_end);
    $('.toggle-item').css('display', 'inline-block');
  });

  socialBtn.on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.toggle-item').remove();
  });
})
```

```css
.social-buttons {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.social-buttons .social-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.social-buttons .social-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.social-buttons .btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.social-buttons .btn i {
  margin-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.social-buttons .facebook-btn {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.social-buttons .twitter-btn {
  color: #00b6f1;
}

.social-buttons .google-plus-btn {
  color: #da5333;
}

.social-buttons .pinterest-btn {
  color: #bb232c;
}

.social-buttons .stumbleupon-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #f15a24;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}


/* toggle item */

.social-buttons .toggle-item {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  height: 27px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: default;
}

.social-buttons .toggle-item:after,
.social-buttons .toggle-item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -9px;
  top: calc(50% - 4px);
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid #ccc;
}

.social-buttons .toggle-item:before {
  content: '';
  border-right: 4px solid #f9f9f9;
  left: -8px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>

<ul class="social-buttons">
  <li class="social-item">
    <span class="btn facebook-btn" data-value="facebook" aria-label="facebook">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  </li>
  <li class="social-item">
    <span class="btn twitter-btn" data-value="twitter" aria-label="twitter">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  </li>
  <li class="social-item">
    <span class="btn google-plus-btn" data-value="google plus" aria-label="google plus">
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  </li>
  <li class="social-item">
    <span class="btn pinterest-btn" data-value="pinterest" aria-label="pinterest">
            <i class="fa fa-pinterest-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
  </li>
  <span class="toggle-item">
        some text
    </span>
</ul>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ.

Comment: к сожалению `overflow: hidden;` не решает проблему, в вашем примере всплывающий блок по-прежнему то появляется, то исчезает при ховере в области правого бордера иконок. Заметил что это каким-то образом связано с уголком на всплывающем блоке - если его убрать, все отрабатывает как положено..

Comment: разобрался в чем дело. У одного из псевдоэлементов для уголка на всплывающем спане был установлен `z-index`, он перекрывал саму иконку. Кпц, сколько времени на такой пустяк. Благодарю вас за помощь и справку по "доступности" :)